# Adding filter criteria to Azure Service Bus Subscriptions

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I'm using Azure Service Bus Explorer in managing subscriptions for existing Azure Service Bus topics. Now we have a new Topic that will receive messages from multiple source systems. Based on the source system i need to create different subscriptions. Below are the sample messages that we recieve

Message1:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "id": "20190501",
    "source": "system1",
    "body": "{\r\n  \"Addressid\": \"74C9\",\r\n  \"Start\": \"2016-07-17T21:06:10.983\",\r\n  \"OrgID\": \"7204055\",\r\n  \"Email\": \"test@gmail.com\",\r\n  \"DeptID\": 998\r\n}",
    "createDate": "2019-05-16T12:47:52.4658011Z",
    "isDeleted": false
  },
  "operation": "POST"
}
```

Message2:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "id": "20190501",
    "source": "system2",
    "body": "{\r\n  \"AC_ID\": \"74C9\",\r\n  \"Name\": \"Name1\",\r\n  \"InventoryID\": \"4055\",\r\n  \"OtherID\": 998\r\n}",
    "createDate": "2019-05-16T12:47:52.4658011Z",
    "isDeleted": false
  },
  "operation": "POST"
}
```

I need to create two subscriptions with filter condition

Subscription1: `with filter as  "source": "system1"`

Subscription2: `with filter as  "source": "system2"`

Please help with me correct filter expression for the above service bus subscriptions that i need to create using service bus explorer.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Service Bus subscriptions operate on message headers/properties only.
You can have either [Boolean, Correlation, or SQL filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters). [`SQLFilter` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.sqlfilter) implements filtering that is beyond simple comparison and the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter) is a SQL-language based.

For example, `"user.source='system1'"` or `"user.source in ('system1', 'system2')"`

In your scenario, I'd use a correlation filter just because there's no need in SQL filter complexity. As well as you're interested in subscriptions, each with a distinct value used for filtering messages out. You'll find an example in [this post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/asb-subs-with-correlation-filters).

Regardless if you use SQL of Correlation filter, filtering can only take place on the properties. You'll have to promote "source" value from the body of your message into one of the headers, system header or a custom header.

To see topics in action, there are a few official samples:

- [Topics: getting started](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/TopicsGettingStarted/README.md)
- [Topic filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/TopicFilters/readme.md)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion will try and make the change.

Comment: This will hopefully save someone else some time. If you have special characters in your user defined properties (ex: '-') use the following syntax in Azure Service Bus Explorer (or any place) to reference the property in a SQL filter:

`user."X-Custom-Property"='ValueToCompare'` or `"X-Custom-Property"='ValueToCompare'`

where 'X-Custom-Property' is your property name.